# Docusign date tag format and default language

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Is it possible to set the default date format for a tag?
Also the default language? At the moment I've noticed it is set to US English.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to DocuSign after following this URL - https://account-d.docusign.com/me/#/languageandregion (Assuming developer account) and you can modify this.
[image]

You can then do this:
[image]

Comment: thanks! I'll try this. Will it also allow me to change the data format?